# Whats a metric that combines % of errors with tot number of instances

Tags: data-visualization

I'm looking for a metric to use to track the severity of certain errors in our microservices.

E.g. read time outs against an external service. On the x-axis I would probably have timeintervalls, say every 10 minutes. On the y-axis the value of the metric.

At first I thought the value would be number of timed out requests. But that's not dead on since the number of time outs needs to be put into relation to the total number of requests.

So second I thought the percentage of timed out requests. But that's not perfect either, since a spike to 100% time outs would not be critical if the total number of requests were 1 during this intervall.

I'm sure this is a common scenario in logging and performance metrics visualization.

Comment: Your metric seems to the same for both instances, is the second bound by some time period? Both seem like an error rate. Can you get the amount of successful requests?

Comment: @NathanMcCoy Not sure I understand what you mean. The first is total number of errors per timeintervall. The second is tot.#.of.errors / tot.#.of.requests per timeintervall. 
Yes I have the amount of succesful requests.

Comment: Oh i see you would like a count, or a normalised form [0, 1]. I will try to respond below

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, errors on your microservices could be calculated as follows:

## Time-Out Error Metrics

### Time-Out Error Count [TOEC]

This is just a raw count, of how many time out errors you have.

This will be bound by some time interval, say every 10 min.

```
TOEC = count of time-out requests in interval
```

### Time-Out Error Proportion [TOEP]

This is a proportion of time-out requests errors you have.

This will be bount by some time interval, say every 10 min.

```
TOEP = count of time-out requests in interval / count of all requests in interval
```

This is a type of [error rate](https://en.wikipedit a.org/wiki/Error_rate)

## Other Metrics

There are other standard metrics, There might be some that look of interest to you here [Wikipedia: Precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)

I have a feeling there may be other types of errors and successes in your domain, if you look at the wikipedia article, and without more information, I believe your  `time-out errors` are equivalent to `TN` which are `True Negative`s.

If you can define the other ones (`FN`, `FP`, `TP`) you could in theory use any of the standard metrics on the wikipedia article. This would give you a lot of information about how to interpret `how well` your microservice is performing.